Почему не сохранят данные в ACF WordPress?
Установил плагин ACF | Advanced Custom Fields for WordPress , сделал все настройки, без дубликатов (main_text_1, main_text_2, main_text_3) и т.д. . Но при сохранении какой либо информации на страницах: текст, фото, видео , ничего не сохраняет. После обновления страницы, поля пустые. Не один год работаю с ACF и раньше такой проблемы не наблюдал. Кто сталкивался с такой проблемой?

возможно битая база, запрет на запись и тд...

Для начала надо проверить, пишет ли вообще хоть что-то в медиа. Если, да. То подключаем дебагер и смотрим на логи ошибок. Вариантов всего два, либо проблема в ядре WP либо в плагине. Я тоже думаю, что у вас стоит ограничение на запись документов, а может какой-то хитровымученый кеш или CDN подключен.
Если это всё же плагин, то разворачиваете Локально, если проблема ушла, значит в настройках сервера.
На самый крайний случай, заходите в базу данных сайта, и ищете по ключам ACF есть ли указаные кастомные поля в wp_posts или чемт-то похожем.
